# Issue to properly cast an event including a customized EventArgs

Tags: c#, events, eventargs

I am working on a Win Form.
One of my button's on click event would need to accept a customized argument (heritated from EventArgs):

```
private void B_Say_Click(object sender, Custom_EventArgs e) //instead of EventArgs e
{
....
}
```

(The reason is that this method might be called when I hit the button, but also in different other contexts where I need to get custom data (that I want to pass via the Custom_EventArgs  ).

Of course I have included a derived class:

```
 public  class Custom_EventArgs : EventArgs
  { 
      public string say_string;
  }
```

The compiler generates this error for line:

```
this.B_Say.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.B_Say_Click);
```

Error   3   No overload for 'B_Say_Click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

If I try to use the generic version of EventHandler :

```
this.B_Say.Click += new System.EventHandler<Custom_EventArgs>(this.B_Say_Click);
```

I get :
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler'

I suppose that  buttons' associated events' signature in System.Windows.Forms.Button class only accept EventHandler.

Since Custom_EventArgs derives from EvenArgs, I suppose that we can explicitaly cast Custom_EventArgs to Eventargs to solve the problem but I am not sure how to do it?

If casting is not a solution, is there another solution?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You can't replace the signature EventArgs with your own.  The Button class wouldn't know how to generate it, or populate the say_string field.  Which makes it a little pointless.  You can use the Button's Tag property, and then in the event, cast the sender object to a button, then examine the Tag property.  Not pretty, but it's not clear why your button should be doing more work than just providing a clicking mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not change signature of event. However, you can check the type of passed event arguments.

```
private void B_Say_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var customArgs = e as Custom_EventArgs;
    if (null != customArgs) {
        // do what you want
    }
}
```